How to avoid vscode html formatter to put open tags at the end of a line
I have an html file which I'm working on vscode. It is a big file that I got by converting a pdf file to html with an online converter.
The tags have inline css style, which results in a bunch of big lines. When I use auto indentation from VSCode, this is what I get:
<div style="BUNCH_OF_STYLES"><p>here is a
    broken text inside bad formatted paragraph</p>
</div>

And this is what I want:
<div style="BUNCH_OF_STYLES">
    <p>here is a continuous text inside well formatted paragraph</p>
</div>

I'm not sure if just increasing the maximum number of characters in a line would solve this, since I have no problem in breaking the text inside the tag. I just don't want that opening tags are placed in the end of lines.
This is another format I would accept:
<div style="BUNCH_OF_STYLES">
    <p>
        here is a broken (big) text
        inside well formatted paragraph
    </p>
</div>

PS: I tried some html formatting extensions, and they have the same behavior.

If you turn off word wrap, what happens?  Is the text coming over "broken" (i.e., with a newline inserted) from the online converter?

It does not affect in anything. The text is coming in a minified format.
